# Display ID3D11Texture2D* in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, texture2d, sharpdx

What is the best way to show ID3D11Texture2D* in WPF? The problem is that I have an unmanaged third-party library which produces ID3D11Texture2D as an output. I want to show this texture in WPF without hosting an unmanaged window. I've found SharpDX the powerful DirectX wrapper, also there is DXElement which can render Texture2D, but I need somehow initialize managed Texture2D class with unmanaged ID3D11Texture2D*. The performance is also critical so I would really appreciate if someone can advice me how to solve this problem in a most efficient way.

P.S. WPF application is running on Windows 7.